# D3 Axis transition

Tags: transition, axis

The visualization is a bar chart in which the range of the bar heights is great (several orders of magnitude).  I have built a transition triggered by a click that increases the heights of all the bars by a multiplicative amount.  I would also like the y-axis ticks and labels to transition to the new scale of the bars.  I have altered the domain of the y-axis scale.  The bar height transition works fine.  The axis transition does nothing.I cannot seem to get the axis  transition correct.  Can anyone help?

The code is a simple example of what I am trying to do - data is fixed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/d3.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.axis, .axis text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.tick text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    fill: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var xSize = 900,
ySize = 500;

var data = [10000, 3000, 100, 40, 10, 5, 1];

var margin = {top:40, right: 40, bottom:60, left: 60};
var width = xSize - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = ySize - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var barwidth = width / data.length;
var xscale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length]).range([0, width]);
var maxData = d3.max(data);
var yscale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, maxData]).range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xscale).orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yscale).orient("left");

var fieldView = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", xSize)
    .attr("height", ySize)
    .on("click", update)
;
var chart = fieldView
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
;
var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {return xscale(i);})
    .attr("y", function(d) { return yscale(d);})
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - yscale(d);})
    .attr("width", barwidth)
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
;

chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
;

chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
;

var transitionScale = 1;
var transitionMultiplier = 5;
var transitionYscale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, maxData])
    .range([height, 0]);
function update() {
    // new multiplier for data
    transitionScale *= transitionMultiplier;
    // update to y axis domain
    yscale.domain([0, maxData / transitionScale]);
    // transition the bars
    bar
        .transition()
        .attr("y", function(d) {return yscale(d);})
        .attr("height", function(d) {return height - yscale(d);})
        .duration(2000)
        .ease("linear")
    ;
    // transition the y-axis
    chart
        .selectAll(".y axis")
        .transition()
        .call(yAxis)
    ;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the axis transition selection from:

> chart.selectAll(".y axis")

to:

> chart.selectAll(".y.axis")

causes the axis to transition correctly.  I don't know why, however.

Comment: Ah, i do. "chart.selectAll(".y axis")" is an invalid selection, as there is no <axis> element in the dom. With that selection, you are trying to select all the <axis> elements that have a parent element with the class "y".  Also, when you create your axis, you do: " .attr("class", "x axis") ". You are actually setting 2 classes on the element. So if you would want to select all elements which have those two classes, you need to do chart.selectAll(".y.axis"). I hope that makes sense :-)

Comment: I think I understand.  Since I set two classes "y" and "axis"  when I created the dom object "g" to contain the y axis, then a "chart.selectAll(".y") is sufficient to select the y axis for transition.  I found this to be true.  Thanks for the help.